# Cassandra + Spark vs MySQL + Spark

Tags: mysql, cassandra, apache-spark

I have to design a piece of software on a three layer architecture:

- A process periodically polling a data source such an ftp to inject in a database
- A database
- Spark for the processing of the data

My data is simple and perfectly suitable for being stored in a single RDMS table, or I can store it in Cassandra, then periodically I would need Spark to run some machine learning algorithms on the whole set of data.

Which of the database better suits my use case? In detail, I do not need to scale on multiple nodes and I think the main underlying questions are:

- Is simple querying (SELECT) faster on Cassandra or MySQL on a simple table?
- Does the Spark Connector from Cassandra benefit of some features of it that will make it faster than a SQL connector?

Comment: Simple select would be faster on MySQL, but loading into sharded Cassandra would be faster. If you data fits into a single node, why don't you use something like R for analysis? And why don't you consider PostgreSQL + MADlib?

Comment: That's the sort of answer I was looking for, thank you. I need to perform some data transformation from the SQL before applying the machine learning algorithm. I am concerned about the fact that  R is weakly typed and not easy to use in a continuos integration process, are my concern reasonable?

Comment: You are right that R is weakly typed, but it is the language with the best ML capabilities you might ever have. Much simpler to use, 100 fold more algorithms and their tunables, etc. In my opinion using distributed framework for machine learning should be avoided in all the means unless it is mandatory - for me it is the case when your data does not fit into memory on a single node, your algorithm is simple and data sampling gives you bigger error than the distributed algo

Comment: Well, you can try with Python, an Pandas.

Comment: Although it's not much applicable in your case, when you have data that fits into just one machine, but spark cassandra connector uses knowledge of spark worker and cassandra nodes being collocated - faster querying and generally speaking spark and hadoop (map reduce engine) can be pretty good at failing instance of anything not distributed enough - many workers at once would read the data from the source - that'd be from smth bad from  bottleneck to a crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL if data size is less than 2Tb. Select on MySQL table will be more flexible than in Cassandra.
You should use Cassandra when your data storage requirement crosses single machine. Cassandra needs careful data modeling to be done for each lookup or Select scenario.

You can use suggested approach below for MySQL Spark Integration

[How to work with MySQL and Apache Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718382/how-to-work-with-mysql-db-and-apache-spark)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on Data : size, integrity, scale, Flexible schema sharding etc.

Use MySQL if:

1. Data size is small ( in single digit TBs)
2. Strong Consistency( Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation & Durability) is required

Use Cassandra if:

1. Data size is huge and horizontal scalability is required
2. Eventual Consistency ( Basically Available Soft-state Eventual consistency)
3. Flexible schema
4. Distributed application.

Have a look at this [benchmarking article](http://vschart.com/compare/apache-cassandra/vs/mysql) and this [pdf](http://www.datastax.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/WP-DataStax-MySQLtoCassandra.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use a sql database as mysql, cassandra only should be used if you need to scale your data in bigger proportions and along many datacenters. The java cassandra jdbc driver is just a normal driver to connect to cassandra, it doesn't have any especial advantages over other database drivers.