# SparkSQL read from MySQL database table using Python

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a 'user' table in MySQL. I want to read it to my Spark SQL program. How can I read the table from MySQL to the Apache Spark's SparkSQL module using Python? Is there a connector I can use for this task? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

There is a [similar question answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718382/how-to-work-with-mysql-db-and-apache-spark). Start `pyspark` like this

```
./bin/pyspark --packages mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38
```

Then just run

```
sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql",
driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
dbtable="user",
user="root",
password=""
).load().take(10)
```

This would most likely just work. But this depends on your mysql set-up, so if it doesn't try changing password, username, db-url and other settings.