# PySaprk: spark-submit is not able to perform the desired job

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I am new to PySpark. I am using the following `spark-submit` process to load a table in Hive in cluster.

```
/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark2/bin/spark-submit --driver-class-path /path/to/driver/sqljdbc4-3.0.jar --jars /path/to/driver/sqljdbc4-3.0.jar --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn /home/meter/myfile.py
```

Whenever I am running this, I am getting myriads of errors. Like

```
1. pyspark.sql.utils.analysisexception u'path file:/root/spark-warehouse/table_name already exist
2. Couldn't find driver for com.microsoft.sqljdbc # something like this
3. Some other staging related errors
```

Bottom Line: I am not able to create a Hive table using the above `spark-submit` code. My Python script is as below

```
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext,SQLContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("myapp")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sql_cntx = SQLContext(sc)
df_curr_volt = sql_cntx.read.format("jdbc").options(url="url",dbtable="table").load()
hc = HiveContext(sc)
df_cv_filt.write.format("orc").saveAsTable("df_cv_raw")
```

Based on stackoverflow search, it seems that I need to modify the `conf` definition above. Or I have to add `Hive` metastore `hive-site.xml` in the `spark-submit`.

Or May be I am missing out something which is not known to me.

My Question is: what is the correct `spark-submit` code I should use? Or is there anything I need to modify in the above python code and then run the `spark-submit`? Or shall I use `spark2-submit`? 
P.S: I am using PySpark 2.0.

**Update**

I have finally zeroed down the error now. This is after some trials after reading few other stackoverflow posts.
Infact, I have changed the `spark-submit` to the following.

```
/usr/hdp...bin/spark-submit --driver-class /path/to/sqljdbc4-3.0.jar --jars /path /to/ sqljdbc4-3.0.jar --master yarn /path/to/.py
```

And post this, I am getting error as follows.

```
staging error.could not find registered driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver #similar to this line.
```

Interestingly, the same method is working fine when `scala` is used. 
Please do let me know how to tackle this now.

Comment: Any one please?

Comment: Did you post all your code? Have you tried to submit a simple job to spark that just load the mysql table? This way you'll be able to validate that spark-submit is working fine before dealing with hive.

Comment: When I run the above python code from pyspark shell, it works fine. In fact earlier, I was successful in `spark-submit` when no `JDBC` was involved.

Comment: when you say it was working, you mean it was working without jdbc, right? so the problem comes from how you initialize jdbc parameters. you can check this topic with jdbc/spark example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36830933/sparksql-read-from-mysql-database-table-using-python

Comment: @HichemBOUSSETTA: Yes, the `spark-submit` worked without `JDBC`. So what I have deduced is there is some problem in accessing the `JDBC` driver class.

Comment: In the link above, pyspark has been launched by specifying the jdbc connector library to be used  (./bin/pyspark --packages mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38). So my guessing is you need either to add manually the jar connector of jdbc in pyspark class path (the directory where spark java dependencies are located) or you add it manually when you start pyspark through command line

Comment: Yes I have seen this link. In my case I need to see what is the MS SQL Server connector. Can you please guide me in finding the right MS SQL Connector? And do I need to paste that connector path somewhere in Python script ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'll try to test this tonight or tomorrow and let you know!

Comment: Hey, did you manage to get the jdbc connector for MS SQL Server? You can get it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017. Actually, I just made a test with mysql and didn't have any issue because my cloudera machine seems to already include required connectors. The spark-submit command succeeded. MS SQL Server connector is a jar that you can include in the submit command as you did. It is named mssql-jdbc-7.2.1.jre8.jar

Comment: @HichemBOUSSETTA: Yes I used mssql-jdbc-6.4.jre8.jar. For our `scala` work it is already present.

Answer (score 1):

```
df_cv_filt.write.format("orc").saveAsTable("df_cv_raw").
```

saveAsTable: This will create a table and since the table already exists it wont allow  unless you use overwrite

```
df_cv_filt.write.mode('overwrite').format("orc").saveAsTable("df_cv_raw")
```

or you have use insertInto with your data

```
data.write.mode("append").insertInto("my_table").
```

Also, make sure you have read access to the jar file and its of the correct version corresponding to the sql-server.

Comment: I have changed the table name from `df_cv_raw` to some other name. Then it is giving `com.microsoft.sqljdbc driver could not found error`. However, when I am running the python script from `pyspark` shell, it is running absolutely fine.

Comment: Can you check if the enviorment variables are correctly set and both pyspark and spark-submit are pointing to the same set  of libraries

Comment: Yes they were it seems. The problem lies in JDBC driver. Anyway I figured that out by the way I mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1):

So I could not trace out the actual reason behind `spark-submit` failure (despite providing correct `mssql-jdbc` driver.

However, I came across another novel way to perform the `spark` jobs. 
I am using `$python /home/meter/myfile.py`. In the `myfile.py` I have added `properties` as `"driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"` inside the `sql_context.read` method.

I am able to see the Hive tables being created.