# Apache Spark : Is it good to use structured data

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, hdfs, distributed-computing, bigdata

One query, i have two bigger Tables A (40 GB) and B(70 GB) in Mysql, I often requires join from both tables. I do not use join in query as it never returns result. Please consider all tables are well indexed.

I take data from table A and than using that data I find matching records in table B in chunks. I process this joined data further. The whole process takes time, depending on how much processing I do.

I know Spark can also be used for distributed computing.

Question 1: If I put this data to HDFS and than process it through apache spark having 5 nodes in cluster can give me a faster result? I think the answer is yes.

Question 2: Is changing a structured data (from MySql) to HDFS can be considered a good approach?

Comment: What do you mean a better result? Faster? Also what do you mean Unstructured Data?

Comment: Spark can connect to MySQL through JDBC drivers, so why do you need to export to HDFS?

Comment: And exporting to HDFS still results in structured data, regardless if you put into Hive or just CSV files

Comment: I need Table A and Table B data several use cases. Hitting mysql for every use cases is not desirable. So if i put this data to HDFS it will load faster than mysql, so planning to fetch this to HDFS only once in day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I going to get a faster result?

It *depends*!

You see [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing) makes sense only when dealing with [bigdata](/questions/tagged/bigdata). If the data are not big enough, then *communication costs* and *job scheduling* would dominate the execution time, resulting in a slower execution time than in the serial execution!

Of course, this would have a good impact on your application, if you could utilize more than one machines/nodes, since as discussed your data is not that big for MySQL.

So, if your machine is unable to tackle them by its own, setting up a cluster with your machine as a master, and a virtual-machine as a slave for example would not give any speedup at all, it would in fact, most likely, be slower!

> Do I have to put my MySQL data to HDFS?

*Not really!*

You can use `mySqlContext` via jbdc format, as discussed in: [How to work with MySQL and Apache Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718382/how-to-work-with-mysql-db-and-apache-spark)

Answer (score 2):

150 gigs is not that much for MySQL. Spark will not help you if your computer cannot handle the join. You can upload the data to google bigtable or amazon relation data store and try it out. otherwise, you can just create table #3 by joining the two tables. Make sure the column on which you are joining is indexed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do.

Yes, Spark is very good in dealing with structured data, please read about DataFrames. You can write SQL queries on your data and this queries will be optimized and translated to RDD invocations.

But it very depends what are you doing.

1. Real time queries from website, i.e. update order, update customer -> sorry, in my opinion Spark will be an overhead. Optimized MySQL with indexes SHOULD be enough. For real-time cache please look at grids, such as Oracle Coherence, GridGain/Apache Ignite, Hazelcast.
2. Reporting and analysis, both batch, streaming analyzis upon some time window and adhoc analysis -> Spark will be great and can speed up your job.
3. ETL for analysis services -> again, Spark will be great tool to speed up jobs. One company (sorry I cannot tell you name in public) wrote ETL process for his customer, instead of 6 hours using old tools, now ETL duration time is 15 minutes. Just bulk read from database, some preparations, transformations, grouping and put into warehouse database. However, customer must pay for cluster and maintain tool. In that case this cost is very low, compared to potential money they can earn.

Spark can read from MySQL. However, if you're doing just batch analysis, I recommend you to dump data each day on HDFS. It will decrease number of queries and load to MySQL database.