# Spark Streaming: How to efficiently save foreachRDD data into Mysql Database?

Tags: java, mysql, spark-streaming

We are going to build a real-time computation system, Also want to save processed data into Mysql Database, here's the code below:

```
splitWordInfo.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
            rdd.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<String>>() {
                // Default Serial ID
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                @Override
                public void call(Iterator<String> eachline) throws Exception {
                    String sql = "insert into test_mm(name,addr) values(?)";
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/dbname", "user", "pass");
                    PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
                    while(eachline.hasNext()){
                        stat.setString(1, eachline.next());
                        stat.executeUpdate();
                    }
                    stat.close();
                    conn.close();
                }

            });
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Does it will open/close mysql connection for each rdd, or for each partition?

And How to efficiently save foreachRDD data into Mysql database. Could anyone do me a favor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to work with MySQL DB and Apache Spark?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718382/how-to-work-with-mysql-db-and-apache-spark)

Comment: I don't think so, I am asking for best practice, not just how to save foreachRDD data into Mysql database, but thx @ruhungry

Comment: As far as I know, each RDD will open a connection to mySQL, so this solution is not best practice to if you want to scale up in the future.

Comment: So any advise about best practice? @Frankie

Comment: @triffic maybe you can use Spark Streaming and HBase in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each RDD partition is like a separate task and your program will get a connection for each partition. It is good to use a connection pool library like Hikari or Tomcat . 
But even with connection pool there will be a cost of communication with database. That you can not avoid in this model.