# Using hive external metadata in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have my metastore in external mysql created using hive metastore. My metadata of the table is in external mysql. I would like to connect this to my spark and create dataframe using the metadata so that all column information is populated using this metadata.

How can I do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spark-Jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718382/how-to-work-with-mysql-and-apache-spark) connection to connect to Mysql and query **hive metastore** located in Mysql.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("mysql connect").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

val mysql_df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:<port>/<db_name>").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "<table_name/query>").option("user", "<user_name>").option("password", "<password>").load()

mysql_df.show()
```

**Note:**

We need to add [mysql connector jar](https://acadgild.com/blog/loading-mysql-data-into-spark) and start your spark shell with the jar (or) include jar in your eclipse project.