# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o43.load. : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:

Tags: python, mysql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to make a connection using PySpark and MySQL (JCDB connection) I am do in it LOCAL I just want to check and play around I follow this post (https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-windows-pyspark-4498a5d8d66c) and in fact everything works until I try to read the mysql database. here the code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').\
     config('spark.jars.packages', 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.44').\
     appName('test').getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format('jdbc').\
        option('url', 'jdbc:mysql://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:3306').\
        option('driver', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver').\
        option('user', 'xxxxxxxxxxx').\
        option('password', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').\
        option('dbtable', 'dbname.tablename').\
        load()

  df.printSchema()
```

Again the sparksession works but when I run the read database I got the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-d85d72d23ebe> in <module>
      4       option('user', 'xxxxxxx').\
      5       option('password', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx').\
----> 6       option('dbtable', 'dbname.tablename').\
      7       load()
      8 

C:\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    164             return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    165         else:
--> 166             return self._df(self._jreader.load())
    167 
    168     @since(1.4)

C:\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1284         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1285         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1286             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1287 
   1288         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     96     def deco(*a, **kw):
     97         try:
---> 98             return f(*a, **kw)
     99         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    100             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

C:\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o87.load.
: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'dbname.tablename WHERE 1=0' at line 1
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2487)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:179)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

I have check it the *MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax* but everything is OK, I tried to run the data directly in Myworkbench and works perfectly...

I am using spark spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7 and MySQL MySQL Server 8.0 I am working on Jupyter notebook.

Anybody an idea how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide the version of Spark and MySQL? Have you checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718382/how-to-work-with-mysql-and-apache-spark)

Comment: @ggeop thanks for your answer, I am using spark spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7 and MySQL MySQL Server 8.0 I am working on Jupyter notebook. I have already seen the answer you mention and I have everything sett correctly but still having this Error.