# Can't connect to mysql using pyspark but can with mysql package

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to connect to mysql db using spark using this commands:

```
os.environ['LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN'] = '1'
df = spark.read.jdbc("jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<db_name>", "<table>", properties={"user": "spark", "password": password})
```

and I get this error:

```
Access denied for user 'spark'@'<ip>' (using password: NO) 
Current charset is US-ASCII. If password has been set using other charset, consider using option 'passwordCharacterEncoding'
```

so I tried writing this python code and everything is working without an issue:

```
os.environ['LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN'] = '1'
mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=password, host=host, database=db_name,
                                       raise_on_warnings=True)
```

I tried adding `authenticationPlugins: mysql_clear_password`  to the properties but I get the same error

I also added `"driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"` to the dict of properties and then I get

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o84.jdbc.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

which is weird because without specifying the driver it seems like it can find the driver but has a problem with the connection so I wonder what driver it's using

EDIT: this is how I get the password:

```
boto3_client = boto3.client('rds', region_name=region)
password = boto3_client.generate_db_auth_token(host, port, user)
```

Comment: Your password only has [US-ASCII](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html) characters ?  The variable `password` (in your first attempt) does have the correct values ?

Comment: Did you try a JDBC link like: [jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?user=fred&password=secret](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#:~:text=jdbc%3Apostgresql%3A//localhost/test%3Fuser%3Dfred%26password%3Dsecret) ?

Comment: @Luuk I added the method I used to get the password. its a token from aws IAM.
Also I tried to run something like the link but with a different jar. I ran: `spark-submit ./db_conn.py --driver-class-path mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar --jars mysql-nnector-java-8.0.13.jar` and I get the error `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o84.jdbc.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` if I specify the driver in the command and I get the first error if I don't specify it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
df = spark \
    .read() \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true") \
    .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") \
    .option("user", "root") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .option("dbtable", <table_name>) \
    .load();
```

Reference: [how-to-integrate-apache-spark-with-mysql-for-reading-database-tables-as-a-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718382/how-to-integrate-apache-spark-with-mysql-for-reading-database-tables-as-a-spark)

Comment: I forgot to mention it in my question but I tried this as well, when specifying the driver I get: `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o84.jdbc.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: @JoSSte I read it before I opened the question but my issue was that I'm not sure what driver my spark tries to connect with. I looked at the list of my jars under: `/usr/lib/spark/jars` but all I found was `spark-sql_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar` which does not seems to be the one it's using. and when I specified to use `my-sql-connector.jar` it says it cannot find the suitable Driver...

Comment: @JoSSte I only get this exception when I tell it to look for the driver `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` if I don't tell it the specific driver it finds a different driver automatically and get past that error and raises a different exception with the connection itself.
The problem is that I don't know what other driver its using and I can't find a way to do it. If you know how I can find the driver its using it can help me :)